# Update user meta from checkout page before payment

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Could you help me please - I have separated billing/shipping address form on the checkout page with the button Next. I want save the address in DB via AJAX on click button Next. Now I have right return in POST when I change data in the form address, but the data is not updated in a user profile.

**function.php**

```
    add_action("wp_ajax_userAddressUpdate", "userAddressUpdate");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_userAddressUpdate", "my_must_login");

function userAddressUpdate($user_id) {


    if (isset($_POST['billing_first_name'])) {
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field(($_POST['billing_first_name'])));
        }

        if (isset($_POST['billing_last_name'])) {
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field(($_POST['billing_last_name'])));
        }


}
```

**file.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    $( '#update_address' ).click(function(){
        const billing_first_name = $("input[name=billing_first_name]").length ? $("input[name=billing_first_name]").val() : '';
        const billing_last_name = $("input[name=billing_last_name]").length ? $("input[name=billing_last_name]").val() : '';
        $.ajax({
            url : ajax_object.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data : {
                action: "userAddressUpdate",
                billing_first_name,
                billing_last_name,
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                alert( data.message );
            }
        });

    })

})
```

Comment: I also additionally try using hook woocommerce_save_account_details and many others - but it's not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first, please use only lowercase action name

"updateAddress" -> "updateaddress"

second, you try alert "message", but never returning data from php function.

```
success: function( data ) {
                alert( data.message );
            }
```

third, add return data to your php funtion like:

```
wp_send_json_success(["message" => "done"]);
```

please make sure your ajax call get response from wordpress with code 200, in case you get a 40x, your php code maybe never run.

in php function add `$user_id = get_current_user_id()`